# Powershell Substring 'Quirk'

Tags: powershell, substring

Seeing 'Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.' being thrown when running this bit of code inside a script:

```
$PrinterDriverName = $printer.DriverName
$PrinterMake = $PrinterDriverName.Substring(0,$PrinterDriverName.IndexOf(" "))
$PrinterModel = $PrinterDriverName.Substring($PrinterDriverName.IndexOf(" ")).Trim()
```

Yet $PrinterMake and $PrinterModel are being populated. What I'm trying fathom out is when these two lines are ran selectively, no errors are returned.
Can someone shed some light as to the substring errors are being produced when running this as part of the script please!?
Thanks in advance ...
Wayne

Comment: If `$PrinterDriverName` doesn't contain a `" "`, `IndexOf()` will return `-1` ie. a Length value of less than zero

Comment: Hi Mathias, $PrinterDriverName = "RICOH 201". As mentioned, the variables are being populated as expected ... I'm just trying to understand why the errors are thrown.

Comment: If that's the case, that error shouldn't be thrown. Have you edited it down somewhat? Is something else (more) going on in the actual script where you see the error?

Comment: Hi Mathias, $PrinterDriverName = "HP Deskjet 6100" (as another example). As mentioned, the variables are being populated as expected.  I'm just trying to understand why the errors are thrown.  I forgot to add the second error in my original question which states: Exception calling "Substring" With "1" argument(s): StartIndex cannot be less than zero. - but if the variables are being populated then surely the StartIndex is not less than zero[?]

Comment: It doesn't solve your issue, but you could do this simpler with `-split` by doing `$PrinterMake, $PrinterModel = $PrinterDriverName -split ' ', 2`

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried your suggestion *TheMadTechnician* and no errors are being thrown.  I'll mark this as answered and try figure it out later!

Comment: @TheMadTechnician You should add that as and answer

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't solve your issue, but you could do this simpler with `-split` by doing

```
$PrinterMake, $PrinterModel = $PrinterDriverName -split ' ', 2
```

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't solve your issue, but you could do this simpler with -split by doing $PrinterMake, $PrinterModel = $PrinterDriverName -split ' ', 2 – TheMadTechnician